# Inflation and the current value of my dollar

Tags: savings, calculation, inflation, compound-interest

I am trying to figure out the value of my $100 with a hypothetical 2% constant inflation rate after 30 years.

Here is the scenario: suppose I have $100 laying under my bed and the hypothetical inflation rate is constant at 2% for the next 30 years. I used an online [calculator](https://www.calculator.net/inflation-calculator.html) and here is the result:

[image: Forward Flat Rate Inflation Calculator]

Now my question is, after all these years and calculation what is the current value of my $100? In other words, how much value of that $100 is lost after all these years? (NOTE: I want the exact value or the percentage of value that I lost from $100 or the value that remains after 30 years of inflation [at the 2% rate].)

Comment: The site you link also has a backward flat rate calculator

Comment: To be a bit pedantic, your $100 will still be worth $100 in 30 years, but it will have the same _buying power_ as $55 (100/181) does today.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your $100 at `t=0` will be worth $55.2 thirty years hence.

Something that costs $100 today will cost 100*(1.02)^30 = $181 30 years later. So your original $100 can purchase only 100/181 worth of goods that it could purchase at `t=0`. So its value after 30 years is $100 * 100/181 = $55 in `t=0` dollars. So it will have lost 45% of its value in 30 years.

Comment: So basically inflation happening at a compound rate thus the value reducing at a slower phase? i:e: for each iteration my dollar value reducing for sure but at a slower rate due to compound effect? wherein a simple rate of 2% inflation (not compound) could reduce the value more?

Comment: I just want to know that, does this compound rate of inflation somehow helps to slowly reduce the value hence that is less bad than a simple rate as in simple rate the dollar value loses more at the same time window? @user2371765

Comment: @noobforever What does "compound" and "simple" mean to you?

Comment: @noobforever What you have typed up is compound. Simple is $102, $104, $106, and so on. Compound grows faster than simple. Inflation applies in a compound manner. The cost 30 years later using compound will be more than the cost 30 years later using simple. So your $100 will lose more value through compound. If you used simple for inflation of 2%, the item will cost you $160. So your $100 will be worth $100*100/160 = $62.5. That is, it will lose only 37.5% of its value. But inflation is always calculated using compound.

Comment: sorry! I have deleted and edited the previous comment, please check this once more! according to the example of my post, compound means to me this:https://ibb.co/kH811J1  and simple means 2*30 = 60 so 100-60= 40% @user2371765

Comment: so now it seems like my assumption on simple is wrong? by simple I meant : 2*30 = 60 so 100 - 60= 40%

Comment: @noobforever The link talks about negative rates. Your inflation is positive. If inflation is 2% then what costs $100 today will cost $102 one year later, and 102(1.02) two years later, and so on. Assume you can buy 1 unit of something with $100 today. That 1 unit will cost you $102 one year later. So how much can your $100 that you put under the bed buy you one year later? It is 100/102 units = .9804 units,  right? So your $100 lost 1.96% of its value in 1 year.

Comment: @noobforever I would suggest that you first understand the dynamics of inflation before you try to do the math. That is, first understand what inflation rate of 2% means. Once you get that, you will do the math right.

Comment: The problem is when I am calculating as 100*100/181 = 55.24 this result is matching with the negative compounding like in this picture https://ibb.co/kH811J1. but when I am calculating 100*100/160 = 62.5 is not matching when I am reducing 2% 30 times like in this picture https://ibb.co/m4DsGHd . what am I missing?

Comment: 100*100/181 = 100 * 100/100*(1.02)^30 = 100(1.02)^(-30) =55.24. Matching with what?

Comment: matching with this negative compounding calculation https://ibb.co/kH811J1 . 55.66

Comment: 1.02^30 is not equal to 1+0.02*30. That's why.

Comment: will you please explain in detail why the result looks too similar?

Comment: Which result looks similar? And to what?

Comment: This "100*100/181 = 100 * 100/100*(1.02)^30 = 100(1.02)^(-30) =55.24" to This https://ibb.co/kH811J1  . My thought was on this if inflation reduces my dollar value by 2% in a compounding fashion then why not keeps reducing 2% in every iterating 30 times. basically compound in a negative fashion. the problem is when I did that the result became this https://ibb.co/kH811J1 which is similar to this  100*100/181=55.24

Comment: -2% compound rate of interest is not the same as 2% inflation. Inflation of 2% does not reduce your dollar value by 2% in compounding fashion. Please read my answer to see how it works. That is why I said it is important to understand the dynamics of inflation before you do the math. If you want to see a connection between the two, the effect of inflation of 2% is similar to a compound interest of 2% applied *backward* in time. So, in purchasing power, 100 will reduce to 100(1.02)^-30 in 30 years. See the third answer below.

Comment: "-2% compound rate of interest is not the same as 2% inflation." despite being not the same, why the result looks very similar?

Comment: (1.02)(0.98)  is almost equal to 1. So 0.98 is almost equal to 1/1.02, and so 0.98^30 is almost equal to 1/1.02^30. So 100*0.98^30 is almost equal to 100/1.02^30.

Comment: Now I understood. So I can't just deduct 2% in a compounding fashion in order to calculate inflation even though the result looks similar.

Comment: The example I am about to give you now is completely irrelevant to inflation. Let's say I have 100 dollars In my wallet. I have decided to spend 2% of that $100 every day in a compounding fashion so that I loose lesser and lesser amount every day. "NOTE: My goal here is to spend lesser and lesser amount every day." so can I use the formula of the negative compound rate of interest in this case? So that I loose lesser and lesser amount every day? or there is other better formula than a negative compound rate of interest to fulfills my goal?

Comment: Yes. You can use the formula for negative compound interest rate. Why? Because you start by spending 2% of 100 leaving 0.98 of 100 behind. Then you spend 2% of 98 leaving 98*0.98 behind, and so on. So after, say 10 time periods, you have 100*(0.98)^10 left behind. You spend lesser each passing time period because the 0.02 applies successively to a smaller amount.

Comment: And If I decide that I will spend 2% of that $100 every day in a simple fashion that means deducting $2 every time I spend from the amount that left in my wallet then will I loose faster than the above example? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you will lose faster.

Comment: The reason I brought this topic is that I was so confused by thinking that If I lose 2% of my dollar value every year due to inflation then I should just deduct 2% every year from what I have in my wallet for the sake of simple calculation. Do you recognize my point of confusion now?

Comment: Yes. But there is more to it than just doing this. If you did this then you would calculate that in 30 years, your 100 would become 40 (100-30*0.02*100)whereas they actually become 55.21. You get this 55.21 by applying 2% compound interest backward in time (see third answer which I think deserves more upvotes)- NOT by applying -2% compound interest forward in time.

Comment: "If you did this then you would calculate that in 30 years, your 100 would become 40" that is that, but also when I did the same thing in a compound manner (applying -2% compound interest forward in time) the result came too similar that almost match with the result of "applying 2% compound interest backward in time" and that became the focal point of my confusion. Can you relate to that?

Comment: Yes. It's easy to confuse between the two. But you know now to use 2% backward in time by understanding the dynamics of inflation.

Comment: Yes, now I do. And Thank you!

Comment: one thing I still confused about is that 200% of inflation doesn't mean a 200% loss of value, right? loss of value would be way lesser than that.

Comment: Yes. The loss would be 67%. Just compound backwards to find the remaining value. (1+2)^-1= 0.33

Comment: It is very confusing to see like 2% of inflation is approximately 2% loss of value but in the case of 200% inflation, the loss of value is very less.

Comment: 200% inflation means everything becomes 3 times more expensive. So your money becomes 1/3 as valuable as it originally was. 2% inflation means everything becomes 1.02 times more expensive. So everything becomes 1/1.02 as valuable as it originally was. 1/1.02 is almost equal to 1-0.02 = 0.98. So about 2% value is lost. But 1/3 is not equal to 1-2. That's why. 1/(1+x) is almost equal to 1-x for only small values of x.

Comment: if I take for example 17% inflation instead of 2% then will this "almost equality" factor no longer be almost equal?

Comment: Just check. 17% is also small enough. Compare x^2 with 1 because if x^2 is small 1-x^2 will almost be equal to 1 and so 1/(1+x) will be almost equal to 1-x.

Comment: so what could be the minimum percentage of inflation where the difference would no longer seem to be "almost equal"?

Comment: That's subjective. Maybe, around 32% because 0.32^2 = 0.1024, and 1-0.1024 is not almost equal to 1. But it all depends on what you think is "almost equal". For your 300% inflation, there is certainly not equality.

Answer (score 5):

It's just 1-(100/181.14) = 44.79% Lost.

What remains is 100*(100/181.14) = $55.21

Answer (score 2):

Took a look at generalising the answers others gave.

Turns out to find out how much your money has been eroded away to due to inflation is just a matter of using a negative value for time in the standard compound interest formula.

100*(1.02)^-30 = 55.21

Same answer as everyone else.